# Steganography (writing text into a png file) doesn't work?

Tags: java, steganography

I have a program for writing a text file to a png file, but it doesn't work - the image, when I decode it, returns the incorrect characters and sometimes the image does not show up correctly. Here is my code:

```
public static void readText(String text, int[] pixArr, BufferedImage im, File outFile)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    char[] txt = text.toCharArray(); //Changes text file to array of characters
    int[] eightBit=new int[8]; //stores binary representation of characters
    for (int i=0;i<txt.length;i++){
        int hey=txt[i];
        for (int a=0;a<8;a++){     //converting text to binary
            eightBit[a]=hey%2;
            hey=hey/2;
            }
        eightBit=reverseArray(eightBit);
        insertion(pixArr, eightBit);
        }
    BufferedImage norm = new BufferedImage(im.getWidth(), im.getHeight(),
                                   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    norm.getGraphics().drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
    ImageIO.write(im, "png", outFile);
    }   

public static void insertion(int[] pixArr, int[]eightBit){
    for (int i=0;i<pixArr.length;i++){
        for (int a=0;a<eightBit.length;a++){
            int temp=pixArr[i];
            temp=temp/2;
            temp*=2;
            pixArr[i++]=eightBit[a]+temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want us to debug your home-grown steganography code? Without any errors or suspected lines or anything? Pass.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take a step back from your code and look at where you modify which data structures.

You declare an array `eightBit` to keep track of the eight bits of one byte. That's neat. (It should be a subroutine so that you can more easily debug it.) But you had the results of the output to `insertion(pixArr,eightBit)`. Follow that `insertion()` call and you'll see that you give it the *same* `pixArr` array every single call -- and have no mechanism to write into *different* portions of the `pixArr` array on subsequent calls.

The *best* this routine can offer is writing eight bits.

Which eight bits? The last eight bits.

But I never see the `int pixArr[]` ever being passed back to the code that actually writes the `png`.

I'd strongly suggest breaking this problem apart into much smaller pieces and *test each piece individually*.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you will find your code a lot easier to debug if you space it out and use meaningful variable names. It's not Tetris, you don't have to cram everything into as small a space as possible :)

I definitely agree with sarnold - you should decompose your problem into small, distinct, testable subroutines; this will help you identify the parts of your code that work as well as the parts that don't.

Comment: "It's not Tetris", I like that. :)